# eGPU not rendering 3D content on internal screen

Tags: windows-10, gpu, gaming

I have a Lenovo Carbon X1 6th Gen and Aorus Gaming Box 1070 on which I've updated the firmware, installed the 1803 Windows update, etc. In Windows, the device is seen, can render stuff like 3DMark on an external display, etc. However, if I try and run apps like 3DMark or any games on the internal display, without an external display connected, the app's video freezes, while Audio in apps like Unigine Valley still play and the GPU is working hard. Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRakC.jpg 
I also tried an HDMI Ghost Dongle with screen mirroring and that didn't work either

The weird thing is, in Linux on Ubuntu 18.04, rendering on the internal display works just fine.

Has anyone seen this before? Help, I want to use this for travelling and taking an external monitor is really not a great option!

Comment: Perhaps you need to install/reinstall the Intel Graphics drivers.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielaGarcia! Gave that a try last night too. I went and grabbed the latest from Lenovo's site. Sadly to no avail.

Comment: I suggest you download it directly from Intel (or install and use the automatic tool).

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either.